# Problem porting from RODBCext to odbc and DBI

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, rodbc

Since upgrading to the newest version of R I became aware that RODBCext have been archived. Which is to bad since that have been on of the cornerstones of pushing my results to my database.

RODBCext is quite nice, I can do this for example:

```
conName <- RODBC-connection
conname_new <- DBI/odbc-connection
tbl <- "MySchema.Table1"
nobsQ <- "?,?,?"

dt <- data.table(Col1 = c(1,2,3),
                 Col2 = c("T", "R", "S"),
                 Col3 = c("Blah", "Gah", "Rah"))

sqlExecute(conName, paste0("INSERT INTO ",tbl, " VALUES (", nobsQ, ")"), dt)
```

While I understand that in odbc and DBI I have to loop through my data.tables, make every row in the data.table into a list (columns to rows). That sounds like a worse solution than I have at the moment. The ability to pass a data table as is is pretty attractive. And I would rather not replace that with a bunch of for-loops.

So my question is this, can I port the above sqlExecute-snippet to DBI/odbc syntax without having to resort too for-loops?

Comment: You definitely do not need to loop through your data row-by-row to insert it into the database, that would be abhorrently slow. (In fact, I recall [benchmarking `RODBC` and `DBI`/`odbc`](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/1ea2a1de11fc1f0aa391f9977766ccec) and inferring that that was what `RODBC` is doing, not `DBI`.) To insert the data, juse use `dbWriteTable(conname_new, tbl, dt)`.

Comment: If you haven't already see them, https://dbi.r-dbi.org/ and https://db.rstudio.com/ are the two best sources for learning/using `DBI`.

Comment: ErrantBard, any progress or more question on this?

Comment: @r2evans Ah, that's great. We left RODBCext as is as I'm on parental leave. But that sounds resonable, I'll take a look at that when I get back